# Drupal 7 Core Module Function for node_save?

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 7, i want to put a additional code when the `Save` button is `Clicked` (Saving) in "a content" form (New or Edit).

I don't want to know the hook (because i don't want to make an obvious `Custom Module`). Because i don't want to let other users know the operation by having a obvious Custom Module which will be listing inside the Module Panel. So i want to make a `Silent Customization` inside the `Existing Drupal Core Module (correspondence Function)`.

Thats why I just want to know `the Function in the Core Modules` which finally process the Node Save task.

- Can anyone please describe which `Function (in Core Modules)` is finally processing the Drupal Node Save? (Save` finally may be for both New Item Insert or existing Item Edit.)

Answer (score 3):

[**DO NOT HACK CORE**](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)

Now that's out of the way, let's continue.

The way I see it, you have a couple of options:

1) Use [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

> The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Although this will allow people to see that there is code being run.

2) Create a custom module, but in your info file make use of the [hidden](http://drupal.org/node/542202#hidden) property:

> As of version 7.x, modules and themes may specify that they should not
>   be visible on the modules page by adding hidden = TRUE. This is
>   commonly used with testing modules used with SimpleTest where
>   end-users should never enable the testing modules.

Comment: `(2) Create a custom module, but in your info file make use of the hidden property` also create a separate physical module folder inside. So, for `Rules`, finally the point is, `Can i run (set to call) my code when a Content is Saved/Edited, by using Rules?`

Comment: If you enable PHP filter then you can put your custom code in an action for rules.

Comment: Although I'm not sure of any use case why you'd want to hide a custom module.  If someone can see the fact that there's an extra module file there, then you're probably already screwed from a security point of view.

Comment: Ya i know the risks and i've done 2~3 core customizations. So instead of discussion about risk now, can i please know about the thing i just want to know?

Comment: Security through obscurity is a waste of time, concentrate on locking down the system through proper means (user permissions/file permissions/server-side settings). I'm not sure you'll find much assistance on hacking core here, I know I for one would try to talk anyone down from that particular suicide ledge...you could hurt yourself (and your site) up there :P

Comment: @chapabu will be updating my bio with some contact details soon, just haven't got round to it yet (too much footie on this weekend) :)

Comment: @4lvin 1) Create a rule that has "When content is created" as an action (you can assign many filters to this such as type, author to name but a few).
2) Create a reaction that runs your code using the PHP filter.

Comment: @Clive hehe..no worries - Housework has kept me busy anyway!  As soon as I've got a way of contacting you then we'll do beer and nerd discussion ;-)

Comment: Hi, @Chapabu. Ok now i understand what you mean. But is it (the script call) only for the Drupal Items? Or Can i call to the external script? I mean can i call, for example, `myscript.php` in the Drupal Root folder? (calling by the Rule)

Comment: You can do everything you could normally do with PHP (i.e. `include 'myscript.php';`).